# Программа не принимает get() как строку int tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.geometry('290x290')


def dah():
     messagebox.showinfo("GUI Python", randint(poik1,poik2) )

l1_Entry = Entry(width = 10)
l1_Entry.place(x=170,y=53)

l2_Entry = Entry(width = 10,)
l2_Entry.place(x=170,y=18)

b2 = Button(text = 'Узнать' ,height = 1, width =15, command=dah)
b2.place(x =90,y = 90)

int_h = l1_Entry.get()
int_g = l2_Entry.get()

poik1 = int(int_h)
poik2 = int(int_g)
```

get не хотел принимать строку как int не знаю почему но написал всё правильно даже в интрнете так говорились .При написание кода я хотел что когда водил текст в Entry был как int и вписал в рендинт.
я до сих пор ищу ответ и   пытаюсь разобрать ошибку или я косаглазый
(это мой первый вопрос в stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить данные из текстовых полей сразу после их создания, а после создания там не будет ничего кроме пустой строки. Пустую строку, естественно, не получится сконвертировать в число. Получать данные нужно уже после нажатия на кнопку, т.е. перенести это в функцию `dah`:

```
def dah():
    int_h = l1_Entry.get()
    int_g = l2_Entry.get()

    poik1 = int(int_h)
    poik2 = int(int_g)
    
    messagebox.showinfo("GUI Python", randint(poik1,poik2) )


l1_Entry = Entry(width = 10)
l1_Entry.place(x=170,y=53)

l2_Entry = Entry(width = 10,)
l2_Entry.place(x=170,y=18)

b2 = Button(text = 'Узнать' ,height = 1, width =15, command=dah)
b2.place(x =90,y = 90)

root.mainloop()
```